# How to tune an weighted voting ensemble method?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, ensemble-learning, oversampling, voting-system

I am working with a data with 5 unbalanced labels. These codes are contained of Normalization, Oversampling on Feature Engineering part. A list of 9 ordinary  Machine Learning methods is provided which are used for the classification task. Then, I take advantage of two kinds of ensemble methods of hard voting and weighted voting methods. 10-fold CV has is exploited to validate results.

```py
methods = ['Support Vector Machine', 'Logistic Regression', 'K Neighbors Classifier', 'Random Forest', \
          'Gaussian Naive Bayes', 'Linear Discriminant Analysis', 'Decision Tree', 'Gradient Boosting',\
          'soft_VotingClassifier','hard_VotingClassifier']
```

I would like to know how to tune weights for the soft voting method one?
Here, are the code and results I have right now:

```py
    if method == 'soft_VotingClassifier':
        cl1 = LogisticRegression()
        cl2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
        cl3 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=35)
        cl4 = GaussianNB()
        cl5 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
        cl6 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        cl7 = SVC(C=0.1, gamma=0.0001, kernel='poly')
        cl8 = GradientBoostingClassifier()
        estimator = [(method[0],cl1), (method[1],cl2), (method[2],cl3), (method[3],cl4),\
                     (method[4],cl5), (method[5],cl6), (method[6],cl7), (method[7],cl8)]
        eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=estimator,
        voting='soft', weights=[5, 5, 10, 5, 6, 8, 4, 10])
        
    if method == 'hard_VotingClassifier':
        cl1 = LogisticRegression()
        cl2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
        cl3 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=35)
        cl4 = GaussianNB()
        cl5 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
        cl6 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        cl7 = SVC(kernel='linear',gamma='scale')
        cl8 = GradientBoostingClassifier()
        estimator = [(method[0],cl1), (method[1],cl2), (method[2],cl3), (method[3],cl4),\
                     (method[4],cl5), (method[5],cl6), (method[6],cl7), (method[7],cl8)]
        eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=estimator, voting='hard')
```

Confusion Matrix results on test data:

```
[50  5  1  4  2]
[ 0 13  1  0  3]
[ 0  1  2  1  1]
[ 4  0  0  2  0]
[ 0  3  0  0  2]
```

Accuracy result on test data:

[image: Accuracy result]

For those kind people who want to check my code or even run them, I gonna put the repository link:
https://github.com/aminkhod/kidney_patients_Classification

Comment: Not really an answer but assuming you only care about accuracy I would just take their outputs and give it to a RandomForest maybe with some other relevant data, there may be some things that one model picks up that another doesn't so you want something that can handle that.  Just assigning weights wouldn't.

Comment: Actually, I care about the Confusion Matrix because I have unbalanced data which 3 of the classes have deficient numbers. When I see the random forest CM result, I see none acceptable result for the class of "0" which is the highest quantity.